# What is the difference between this two constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, oop, variable-initialization

What is the difference  between this two constructor?

```
int x, y; //position 

BasePoint(int px, int py) : x(px), y(py) {}
```

and

```
int x, y; //position 

BasePoint(int px, int py)
{
    x = px;
    y = py;
}
```

What is `x(px), y(py)` called? And When do I use this type of variable initialization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First one is doing **initialization** using `initialization-list`, and second one is doing **assignment** using assignment operator.

First one is recommended!

```
BasePoint(int px, int py) : x(px), y(py) {}
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is called initialization-list!
```

Read this FAQ : [**Should my constructors use "initialization lists" or "assignment"?**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6)

The FAQ answer starts with :

> Initialization lists. In fact,
>   constructors should initialize as a
>   rule all member objects in the
>   initialization list. One exception is
>   discussed further down [...]

Read the complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

What is x(px), y(py) called?

These are called initializer lists. What you are actually doing is copying the value of `px` to `x` and `py` to `y`.

Uses:

```
class foo
{
    private:
    int numOne ;

    public:
    foo(int x):numOne(x){}
};

class bar : public foo
{
     private:
     int numTwo;

     public:
     bar(int numTwo): foo( numTwo ), // 1
                      numTwo(numTwo) // 2
     {}
 };

 bar obj(10);
```

**1.** Notice that derived constructor's argument can be passed to base class constructor.

**2.** Compiler can resolve, in this case, which one is argument and which one is member variable. Had if, this needs to be done in the constructor,then -

```
 bar::bar(int numTwo) : foo( numTwo)
 {
     this->numTwo = numTwo; // `this` needs to be used. And the operation is called assignment. There is difference between initialization and assignment.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BasePoint(int px, int py) : x(px), y(py) {}
```

here u  are using the initialization list
so the object when constructed will not go inside the body and initiate those values.it saves time by not entering in the body of the constructor

Another use of this  is when calling the derived class constructor.

where if you use the statement like

```
new derivedclass(a,b,c)
```

and you can write this

```
derivedclass(int x,int y,int z):baseclass(a,b),h(z){}
```